# Evaluation of a computational model by using experimental data

Tags: model, model-evaluation

Actually I'm not sure if the post's title is the right one but if moderators have another one in mind then they should try to change it.

Anyway. In our subject now. I'm not the super-data analyst and thus i will try to describe as better as I can the whole concept.

So. Let's assume that there is an experimental process that one has a polymeric linear organic molecule and under certain conditions (ph, temperature, existence or not of an enzyme etc) this molecule breaks in let's say specific positions. Then these new pieces the researcher loads them to a sequencer machine (imagine something like DNA sequencing platforms) and this machine, reads them and creates as a result a list of all broken pieces.

i.e
Let the `KKKMKKKLMMKKSDDKKKKKKKMMMMMMKMKMKL` be the initial polymer molecule and after the cleavage treatment the following parts of it occurs (as a result of the sequencer):

```
KKKMKKKLM
MKKS
DD
KKKKKKKM
MMMMMKMKM
```

Here I have to mention that by changing the variables said before (ph, temperature, existence or not of an enzyme etc) one can take different or same results.

That was the experimental part. Now let's say that we create a computer software that tries to mimic the way that the above experimental process work by taking into account all these variables. As you will know the results of the software might not be exactly the same with the experiment above and might be something like :

```
KKKMKKKLM
MKKSDD
KKKKKKK
MMMMMMKMKM
```

The idea now is to somehow evaluate and maybe optimize the way the software is working by using a lot of experimental data. For example after a specific process to be able to say that by changing a little bit the pH value in the software the artificial results are getting more close to the experimental ones.

Until now what I thought (and correct me if I'm totally wrong) is to begin with a clustering of the experimental data with respect of those variables (ph, temperature, existence or not of an enzyme etc).

Then search under which cluster the`KKKMKKKLMMKKSDDKKKKKKKMMMMMMKMKMKL` molecule creates the `DD` piece. If there is such cluster take the variables values of it, feed them to the software, re-execute it and see if it gets closer to the experimental data.

Also i though to filter out the variables and keep only the significant ones that helps the clustering and play with them on the software.

So what is your opinion ?

Hope the description is clear and understandable.

Thank you.

Comment: So you're trying to predict the positions at which the polymer breaks given some inputs, right? Do you always start with the same polymer? How is the model parameterized, I.e. what are you trying to optimise?

Comment: Actually polymer could be of any linear combination of these letters.  So I'm not using only this polymer I posted but many of them and be sure that I have experimental data from all of them. It just take into account ph , temperature etc. For example there is an if clause that checks if temperature is between 20 and 25 degrees and the ph at 7 then if polymer has an DDK bond this breaks at DD+K. So I'm trying to optimize this. Maybe this is not true in experimental data and under those conditions there is not such cleavage but instead a cleavage between two Ds (DD) being observed.

Comment: (continue) So after this realization I want to be able to change the algorithm and make it predict that there will be a cleavage between two Ds and not between DK.

Comment: That sounds like a decision tree. You could try fitting one to each mini-polymer (not sure of the proper terminology) you're interested in (treat it as a binary classification - break vs. not break).